# Datatables and Bootstrap sScrollY leaving gap between thead and tbody

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using Bootstrap and Datatables.  I have code to display a table which works fine up to the point where I add sScrollY.  As soon as I add this I get a gap between thead and tbody.

As far as I can see DataTables is splitting the thead and tbody into two seperate tables.  Bootstrap css gives margin-bottom: 20px to the .table class.  So, obviously both tables get this css class applied, giving a 20px gap between the both.

Has anyone come across this?  If so, how did you (can I) solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap and datatables:

(1) are you using the code discussed in this post on the datatables site?
http://www.datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2

(2) are you wrapping the table inside a `.container`?

I don't want to suggest that taking these steps is the only way to make the `sScrollY` work as you expect it to, but I think taking these steps is one option you could use to make the table work as expected.

Here's an example:
**http://jsbin.com/atofot/1**
**http://jsbin.com/atofot/1/edit**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#new-example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        }
    });
});
```

Note in the jsbin code that the sample uses the `DT_bootstrap.css` and `DT_bootstrap.js` that come from the datatables [blog post](http://www.datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2).

Comment: Thank you so much.  Just needed to take a step back from the problem and see what was wrong.  Looks my "DT_bootstrap.js" link was messed up.